# how to run a single command multiple times with a BAT on CMD

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I tried to run the code below, but it gives a prompt. I want the batch file run the command "keygenerator.rb" multiple times.

```
@echo off
:x
:start
"C:\Ruby30-x64\bin\ruby.exe" "D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\keygenerator.rb" >> "D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\output.txt"
goto x
```

Comment: I am sorry if this incorrect, but your code isn't properly formatted in your question body, and the code formatted like this in a batch file definitely wouldn't work...

Comment: i have formatted it now please check

Comment: Did it solve your problem? It should work if your the command is legit, if you still receive errors, then your .rb script has errors...

Comment: Your batch file doesn't give a prompt. So it's either `ruby.exe` or (more probably) the script `keygenerator.rb`. See if you can locate the code that prompts and change/remove it. If this is no option, we need to know this code; maybe we can work around it in batch.

Answer (score 1):

The proper batch file should be like this:

```
@echo off
:x
C:\Ruby30-x64\bin\ruby.exe D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\keygenerator.rb >> D:\folder\folder\folder\folder\output.txt
goto x
```

Check whether this solves your issue or not.

And double quotation marks aren't needed if the path doesn't contain any spaces in cmd.

I had written this:

```
:ping
ping 127.0.0.1
goto ping
```

The result:

[image]

The code I gave you should be working, if it isn't, then the fault is on your ruby script, you should post your ruby script in the question body.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click that tick sign to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

---

- **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)** file:

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal & cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_rb_dir=C:\Ruby30-x64\bin"
set "_rb_log=D:\Full\Path\to\file\output.txt"
set "_rb_scr=D:\Full\Path\to\file\keygenerator.rb"

pushd "%_rb_dir%" & for /L %%i in (1 1 20)do (
     ruby.exe "%_rb_scr%" >>"%_rb_log%"
     timeout 5
    )
    
popd

:: Run from here your next command if need

endlocal
```

---

- Set a limit for your loop, or **`goto :x`** will execute your command indefinitely.

```bat
FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command 
For /L %%i         IN (    1    1  20) DO command
```

Use the **`for /L`** loop, where you can define a limit and
execute your command in **`for /L`** loop until this ***limit is reached***...

---

- One option with real-time monitoring of the current loop execution:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal & cd /d "%~dp0"
set /a "_cnt=0, _run=20"
set "_rb_dir=C:\Ruby30-x64\bin"
set "_rb_log=D:\Full\Path\to\file\output.txt"
set "_rb_scr=D:\Full\Path\to\file\keygenerator.rb"

pushd "%_rb_dir%" 

for /L %%i in (1 1 %_run%)do (
     set "_cnt=1000%%~i"
     ruby.exe "%_rb_scr%" >>"%_rb_log%"
     timeout 2|cmd/v/c "echo/Loop: !_cnt:~-3!/0%_run%"
    )
    
popd 

:: Run from here your next command if need

endlocal
```

---

- Some further reading **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**:

  [√] **[set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[CMD /?](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**

  [√] **[For /L Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**

  [√] **[Pushd | Popd](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)**

  [√] **[Why does call set work differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893287/why-does-call-set-work-differently-in-a-cmd-windows-versus-a-cmd-file)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

  [√] **[Use parentheses/brackets to group expressions in a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)**

- ---

**Inspired by the comment and answer from... [@***Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς***](https://superuser.com/a/1614066/969781)**

> - ***To do the same in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):***
> - *It does more or less the same thing the script posted by **[<strike>***@It Wasn't Me***</strike>](https://superuser.com/a/1613562/969781)**
>
>   **[@***Xeнεi Ξэnвϵς***](https://superuser.com/a/1614066/969781)**  does*. *As it is simple, I will let you understand it by yourself.*

```bat
$Rubybin="C:\Ruby30-x64\bin\Ruby.exe"
$Rubyout="D:\Full\Path\to\file\output.txt"
$Rubycrt="D:\Full\Path\to\file\keyGenerator.rb"

$Limit=Read-Host -Prompt 'Please input loop limit'; 1..$Limit |
  ? {" & '$Rubybin' '$Rubycrt' >> '$Rubyout'"; Start-Sleep -m 550;
    Write-host Loop $_.ToString("000") in $('{0:d3}' -f [int]$Limit) }
```

---

- Some further reading **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

  [√] **[Read-Host](https://ss64.com/ps/read-host.html)**
  [√] **[$Variables in PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.1)**
  [√] **[About *`methods()`* in PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_methods?view=powershell-7.1)**
  [√] **[Use PowerShell to execute an exe](https://4sysops.com/archives/use-powershell-to-execute-an-exe/)**
  [√] **[Loop x number of-times in PoweShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488372/loop-x-number-of-times)**
  [√] **[PowerShell loops: For, Foreach, While, Do-Until, Continue, Break](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-loops-for-foreach-while-do-until-continue-break/)**
  [√] **[How Can I Use Leading Zeroes When Displaying a Value in Windows PowerShell?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-leading-zeroes-when-displaying-a-value-in-windows-powershell/)**

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can learn some PowerShell:

```
$Rubydir="C:\Ruby30-x64\bin"
$Rubyout="path\to\output.txt"
$Rubyscript="path\to\keygenetator.rb"

$N=0; $Limit=Read-Host "Please input loop limit"
While ($N -lt $Limit) { &"${Rubydir}\Ruby.exe" $Rubyscript |
   Out-File -File $Rubyout -Append; Write-Host "Loop $N in $Limit"; $N+=1 }
```

It does more or less the same thing the script posted by **[@It Wasn't Me](https://superuser.com/a/1613562/969781)** does. As it is simple, I will let you understand it by yourself.

And if you want to use for loop:

```
$Rubydir="C:\Ruby30-x64\bin"
$Rubyout="path\to\output.txt"
$Rubyscript="path\to\keygenetator.rb"

$Limit=Read-Host "Please input loop limit"
For ($N=0;$N -lt $Limit;$N++) { &"${Rubydir}\Ruby.exe" $Rubyscript |
   Out-File -File $Rubyout -Append; Write-Host "Loop $N in $Limit" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to loop the `.bat` file is to introduce the `.bat` filename at the end of the `.bat` file. That way, the file will invoke itself again, as it is recognized as a command *per se*.

For example, you have a bat file with just this content:

```
sfc /scannow
my_precious_batch_file
```

And then you save your file as `my_precious_batch_file.bat`.
This will make the `sfc /scannow` command to run, and then invoke the `.bat` again and run the `sfc /scannow` command again. A perfect loop.

Just don't name your `.bat` file the same as a Windows command, or the `.bat` file will run itself again instead of running the Windows command. Like, don't name your file as `sfc.bat`. It will never run `sfc /scannow` this way, it will just flood your screen with the content of the `.bat` file and won't run the command, as it is just invoking itself on the first line. A perfect loop of do-nothing...

Example of this happening by accident:

> In Windows, if you have a command line executable with the same name as your `.bat` filename, and the batch file contains this command, the batch file keeps looping since Windows will execute that `.bat` file instead of the Windows command.

Source: Huseyin Yagli @ Stack Overflow. "[My Batch File keeps looping, but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38434127/19314948)". Jul 18, 2016 at 10:14.